# Does low frequency sound cause people to see apparitions?

Tags: sound, ghosts

There are claims like [this](http://truthseekers.cultureunplugged.com/truth_seekers/2009/12/sounds-of-silence.html) and [this](http://www.cbc.ca/news/technology/ghostly-infrasound-may-explain-the-paranormal-1.2325651) that low frequency sounds can cause people to see apparitions. In certain individuals, low-frequency sound is [claimed](http://www.strangerdimensions.com/2013/06/21/infrasound-the-fear-frequency/) to induce feelings such as fear, dreadfulness or depression and animals are also claimed to react to such sounds. Some films such as Paranormal Activity and Irreversible, a French film  are also [claimed](http://www.bbc.co.uk/arts/0/24083243) to use such sounds to induce fear in audiences. So does low frequency sound cause people to experience weird paranormal experiences and phenomena such as ghost sightings?

Comment: That first article exxagerates to *artificially induce paranormal experiences*, whereas we are probably only talking about your senses being confused. When that happens, who is to say how you are going to interpret that? The article makes more statements *without references*.

Comment: That article even debunks its own claims: *When French’s team crunched the numbers, the only statistically significant association appeared in subjects who scored highly on a test of psychological predisposition to the sort of transcendental feelings generally experienced by epileptics with unstable temporal lobes.* AND *People tend to think about what they’re told to. Asked to track strange feelings, they started noticing them. And the participants’ response rates indeed followed what’s predicted by models of suggestible behavior*. There is no claim.

Comment: I thought someone had shown that there was a resonant frequency with the vitreous humour of the eye and low frequency: http://www.skepdic.com/infrasound.html

Comment: @JanDoggen-Changed the first claim reference to a different site!

Comment: Irréversible certainly induced some fear in me but correlation does not imply causation.